# Magento2 rewrite javascript file from a core module in a custom module

Tags: magento2, module, javascript, overrides, uicomponent

I have created a custom module that uses the UI component

```
<uiComponent name="product_listing"/>
```

Basically, I want to create a javascript file in my module that rewrites/overrides only the fallowing part of that component js file:

```
vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/grid/provider.js:

/**
 * Reloads data with current parameters.
 */
    reload: function () {
        this.trigger('reload');

        if (this.request && this.request.readyState !== 4) {
            this.request.abort();
        }
        console.log(this);
        this.request = $.ajax({
            url: this['update_url'],
            method: 'GET',
            data: this.get('params'),
            dataType: 'json'
        });

        this.request
            .done(this.onReload)
            .error(this.onError);
    },
```

Can someone please guide me trough how to do that in the best and efficient way ? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try 'mixins' feature, all you need is to create requireJS module with extended method like this:

default_mixin.js:

```
define(function () {
    'use strict';

    return function (target) { // target == Result that Magento_Ui/... returns.
        var parent_reload = target.reload;
        target.reload = function () {
            console.log('before reload');
            parent_reload.apply(this, arguments); //call parent reload
            console.log('after reload');
        }
        return target; // new result that all other modules receive 
    };
});
```

requirejs-config.js:

```
config: {
    mixins: {
        'Magento_Ui/web/js/grid/provider.js': {  // Target module
            'My_Module/js/payment/default_mixin': true  // Extender module
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working.... var config = {
 config : {
     mixins: {
          'Magento_Ui/web/js/grid/provider': {  // Target module
          'MyVendor_MyModule/js/default_mixin': true  // Extender module
         }
     }
 }
}; .. and the code in default_mixin.js is exact copy/paste from the example code you gave, but no console.log or alert what so ever...

Comment: is this still a valid solution, because i see its over 6 months old  ? https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1864

Comment: tried this as code for default_mixin ... not working as well ... define(function () {
    'use strict';
    var mixin = {
      reload:function (){
       console.log('ddd');
       alert('3333');
      }
    }
   
    return function (target) { // target == Result that Magento_Ui/.../default returns.
        return target.extend(mixin); // new result that all other modules receive 
    };
});

Comment: I remove pub/static and deploy new static content after every change... what exactly is arguments ?

Comment: yeah, with a mixture between your answer and the github one I made it work, thank you!